# Python Requests - Wait for AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, python-requests

I'm developing a Chess advising Python application, using [lichess.org](https://lichess.org) and I'm encountering difficulties with data retrieval from the site.

I'm trying to use Python requests library for solving this problem, and this is the code I came up with so far:

```
import requests


color = 'black'
fen = '2k4r/ppp1b3/3p4/3Pp3/P1P2P2/BP4p1/3N3r/3R1RK1 w Qk -' 
payload = {'variant' : '3', 'fen': fen, 'timeMode': '0', 'time':'5.0', 
'increment': '8', 'days': '2', 'level': '8', 'color':color}

s = requests.Session()
s.post('https://lichess.org/setup/ai', data = payload)

# Some sort of code to be activated when the AI played his move
```

If the form is submitted correctly, the site will redirect to a playing page (In a different address), in which the site's AI will play his move first.

I'm searching for some way to know when the AI played his turn, and return his move which is documented in the table to the right of the chess board (for example: 'Nf3').

Comment: Can you provide use the data you get when you use `s.get('https://lichess.org/setup/ai', data = payload)`

Comment: I used accidentally get instead of post, my bad. (The problem remains after the post, because I still need to retrieve the data from the new URL)

Comment: Does the URL change every time AI plays move?

Comment: why you are not using flask or django framework, they make all of this very easy

Comment: @Stivan No, the url changes only when you submit the form.

Comment: s= request # not with session

Comment: There seems to be an API for Lichess (https://github.com/lichess-org/api), have you looked into this?

Comment: @AyoubBenayache I am not fimiliar with those frameworks. I'll appreciate an example of how can I use them in order to solve the problem.

Comment: @Tomalak Wow, cant believe I missed it, I will definitely look into it!

Comment: @Ido check this tutorial  https://scotch.io/bar-talk/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask

Comment: The online API documentation page appears to be broken right now, but all the details are in the YAML file. Or maybe the documentation works when you clone the git repo and run it locally.

Comment: @AyoubBenayache Thanks! Highly appreciated!